# Does nvram boot-args="debug=0x10" still speed up Parallels on newer versions with newer macOS releases?

Tags: mojave, performance, virtualization, parallels-desktop, vmware

[As mentioned several years ago](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155193/what-does-sudo-nvram-boot-args-debug-0x10-do-to-my-mac), `sudo nvram boot-args="debug=0x10"` used to speed up virtual machines significantly in both Parallels and VMware.

Has anyone tested to see if this as any empirically beneficial results today or is this entirely non-consequential now?

Comment: According to [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6683965) it was fixed in 10.10.2.

Comment: Interesting and good to know. Perhaps it would be worth confirming again here independently for sanity's sake, yeah, thanks.